# Multiply all numbers in a list - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm really new to haskell and would like to multiply all numbers in an array. For example.:

Array:

```
[3,2,4]   //3*2*4
```

Output

```
24
```

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of ways of doing it in Haskell. 
For instance, you could use:

```
product [3,2,4]
```

or equivalently

```
foldr (*) 1 [3,2,4]
```

or recursively:

```
prod [] = 1
prod (x : xs) = x * prod xs
```

Function `foldr` is the so called list [catamorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism). To understand foldr we need to first understand list constructors. In Haskell, `[3,2,4]` is a syntax sugar for `3 : 2 : 4 : []`, where `:` is list-cons constructor and `[]` is the empty list. Application `foldr f v` replaces every occurrence of `:` in a list by function `f` and the empty list for `v`. Its definition is as follows:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f v [] = v                       -- equation 1
foldr f v (x:xs) = f x (foldr f v xs)  -- equation 2
```

As an example, consider `foldr (*) 1 [3,2,4]`:

```
foldr (*) 1 [3,2,4]     =
3 * (foldr (*) 1 [2,4]) = (by equation 2 of foldr)
3 * (2 * (foldr (*) 1 [4])) = (by equation 2 of foldr)
3 * (2 * (4 * (foldr (*) 1 []))) = (by equation 2 of foldr)
3 * (2 * (4 * 1)) = (by equation 1 of foldr)
= 24
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you explain what the foldr function does please?

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain foldr function. Hope that it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with a fold function:

```
foldr (*) 1 [2,3,4]
```

or...

```
foldr1 (*) [2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `product` function is exactly what you're looking for.
It has also the feature that `product []` equals 1, as you would expect mathematically speaking.

If you look at its definition, you can see that `product` is indeed the *fold* of multiplication (with 1 as neutral element).